# How can I encode a video to h264?

Tags: video, format, h.264, gstreamer, gnuradio

I am trying to send a video file using GNUradio, specifically using GRC. In order to do this I am first obtaining whichever video, in our case we took a 6 second video of us staring and talking to the camera. After this was done we created a "pipe" file I believe is called using mkfifo, both for the input and output file. After that I believe Im supposed to save the video I took in a h264 encoding using a command that I found:

```
gst-launch -e -v v4l2src device="/dev/video1" ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! \timeoverlay halign=right valign=bottom shaded-background=true ! \textoverlay text="Test Video 640x360 25fps" halign=left valign=bottom shaded-background=true ! \x264enc bitrate=498 ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=test1.ts
```

This is giving me an error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc"
```

Ive been trying to find how to solve this and I've installed basically every package or library that exists that may have to do with h264 encoding or x264enc command.

How can I possibly resolve that issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

download and make install [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html)

Comment: I tried doing it but doing it the normal sudo make install gave me 2 print outs.

user@user-Precision-WorkStation-T3400:~/Desktop/x264-snapshot-20120504-2245-stable$ sudo make install
install -d /usr/local/bin
install x264 /usr/local/bin

When I add the sudo make install x264: 
make: `x264' is up to date.

And the same WARNING: erroneous pipeline keeps appearing. Dont know if I maybe downloaded something somewhere else that may be interferring with that make install and Linux isnt able to read the files. Any other possible ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Type `gst-inspect x264enc` on command line.

If it shows that you have it, you need to look for some other problem with pipeline sync.

If it does not show `x264enc`, you need to have `gst-plugin` having x264enc built. Download corresponding tarball probably

```
gst-plugins-ugly
```

Extract it and try installing it with:

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`

`cd` to directory, then

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now it will probably work.